# Cannot find namespace 'SchemaTypes'

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I've some typescript problem with using mongoose...

```
import { SchemaDefinition, SchemaTypeOpts, SchemaTypes } from 'mongoose';

export interface ILockedSchemaDefinition extends SchemaDefinition {
  locked?: SchemaTypeOpts<SchemaTypes.Boolean>;
}
```

The SchemaTypes namespace in the interface body is not found.

But SchemaTypes is found when I create my schema:

```
import { SchemaTypes, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { ILockedSchemaDefinition } from './i_locked_schema_definition';
import { LockedSchema } from './locked_schema';

const schema = new LockedSchema<ILockedSchemaDefinition>({
  x: {
    maxlength: 200,
    required: true,
    type: SchemaTypes.String
  }
}
```

So looks like some bug in the typings of mongoose.
Have you seen this before and do you know a workaround?

Modified from comment below to:

```
import { Schema, SchemaDefinition, SchemaTypeOpts } from 'mongoose';

export interface ILockedSchemaDefinition extends SchemaDefinition {
  locked?: SchemaTypeOpts<typeof Schema.Types.Boolean>;
}
```

Now I've a problem with setting default value:

```
import { Schema, SchemaOptions } from 'mongoose';
import { BaseSchema } from './base_schema';
import { ILockedSchemaDefinition } from './i_locked_schema_definition';

export class LockedSchema<T extends ILockedSchemaDefinition> extends BaseSchema<T> {
  constructor(definition?: T, options?: SchemaOptions) {
    if (!definition.locked) {
      definition.locked = {
        default: false,
        type: Schema.Types.Boolean
      };
    }
    super(definition, options);
  }
}
```

This exception:

**Type '{ default: boolean; type: typeof Boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'SchemaTypeOpts'. Types of property 'default' are incompatible. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'typeof Boolean | DefaultFn<typeof Boolean>'**

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick for the types:

- `SchemaTypes` is purely JavaScript
- `Schema.Types` works with TypeScript

Try the following snippet that seems to work at least regarding the TypeScript compilation:

```
import { Schema, SchemaDefinition, SchemaTypeOpts } from 'mongoose';

export interface ILockedSchemaDefinition extends SchemaDefinition {
  locked?: SchemaTypeOpts<typeof Schema.Types.Boolean | boolean>;
}

export class LockedSchema<T extends ILockedSchemaDefinition> /* extends BaseSchema<T> */ {
  constructor(definition?: T /* , options?: SchemaOptions */) {
    if (!definition.locked) {
      definition.locked = {
        default: false,
        type: Schema.Types.Boolean
      };
    }
    // super(definition, options);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be with typeof... but Type '{ default: boolean; type: typeof Boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'SchemaTypeOpts<typeof Boolean>'.
  Types of property 'default' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'typeof Boolean | DefaultFn<typeof Boolean>'.

Comment: @Markus: what is the code where this TypeScript error occurs?

Comment: @Markus: did I answer your question? The solution is not perfect but should be enough to pass TypeScript compilation. So please vote (▲ or️ ️✓) or add more inputs.

Comment: Well, I've added the stuff to the question. I can use SchemaTypeOpts<any> but not with a type, because either Namespace is not found or the type is not assignable because typeof Type is not Type. Seems to be a bug in the type definitions.